# strtoul() Function- Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a swift iOS program that converts a number into dec, bin, and hex numbers. I've come across the strtoul function, but don't quite understand how to use it, would someone be able to explain it? Thanks!

Comment: Apple has written a huge documentation...

Comment: this has nothing to do with Xcode…

Comment: try "man strtoul" in terminal.

Answer (score 4):

The method strtoul is pretty simple to use. You will need also to use String(radix:()) to convert it to the other direction. You can create an extension to convert from hexaToDecimal or from binaryToDecimal as follow:

Usage String(radix:())

```
extension Int {
    var toBinary: String {
        return String(self, radix: 2)
    }
    var toHexa: String {
        return String(self, radix: 16)
    }
}
```

Usage strtoul()

```
extension String {
    var hexaToDecimal: Int {
        return Int(strtoul(self, nil, 16))
    }
    var hexaToBinary: String {
        return hexaToDecimal.toBinary
    }
    var binaryToDecimal: Int {
        return Int(strtoul(self, nil, 2))
    }
    var binaryToHexa: String {
        return binaryToDecimal.toHexa
    }
}
```

Testing

```
let myBinFromInt = 255.toBinary         // "11111111"
let myhexaFromInt = 255.toHexa          // "ff"

let myIntFromHexa  = "ff".hexaToDecimal          // 255
let myBinFromHexa  = "ff".hexaToBinary           // "11111111"

let myIntFromBin   = "11111111".binaryToDecimal  // 255
let myHexaFromBin  = "11111111".binaryToHexa     // "ff"
```

Answer (score 0):

The [strtoul()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/strtoul.3.html) function converts the string in str to an unsigned long
value.  The conversion is done according to the given base, which must be between 2 and 36 inclusive, or be the special value 0.

Really it sounds like you want to use [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html)

From what it sounds like, you want to convert an unsigned integer to decimal, hex and binary.

For example, if you had an integer `n`:

```
var st = NSString(format:"%2X", n)
```

would convert the integer to hexadecimal and store it in the variable `st`.

```
//NSString(format:"%2X", 10) would give you 'A' as 10 is A in hex
//NSString(format:"%2X", 17) would give you 11 as 17 is 11 in hex
```

Binary:

```
var st = NSString(format:"%u", n)
```

Decimal (2 decimal places)

```
var st = NSString(format:"%.02f", n)
```

Comment: Okay. I assume that the "%2X" is for hex, what would the equivalent be for binary and decimal?

Comment: I've implemented the code, but I the binary and the decimal do not work. The Binary is giving me 000000n-value and the decimal is just giving me 0.00.