# Swift convert a string to a hex int

Tags: swift, hex

I have a string "abcdef" that I want to convert to a hex int 0xabcdef in swift. Any one have any good solutions? It would be nice if I could do something like:

```
var string = "abcdef";
var value = string.toInt(16);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28824904/2303865

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189338/swift-native-functions-to-have-numbers-as-hex-strings.